# Why can't I display a variable in a text field?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that creates a string and I would like for it to be displayed in a textbox on the page. I cannot understand why this does not work.

HTML:

```
<input id="poNum" type="text" name="PO" id="PO" style="width: 310px;" readonly />
```

JS:

```
 document.getElementById("poNum").innerHTML = number;
```

Comment: is `number` the result string of your function?

Comment: inputs use value, not innerHTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 document.getElementById("poNum").value = number;
```

InnerHTML is accessing... well, the actual **inner** html. Where as value is a attribute for inputs (selects, buttons, etc).

Comment: Case closed, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById("poNum").value = number;`

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` elements have values, not inner HTML:

```
document.getElementById("poNum").value = number;
```